# TypeScript: workaround for relative reference path?

Tags: module, typescript, tsd

My goal is to refer to .d.ts files that I've installed with tsd. The [tsd definitions GitHub repository](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/tsd) has examples using paths relative to the source file's location:

```
/// <reference path="../typings/tsd.d.ts" />
```

I find that a potential maintenance issue - if I want to reorganize how my project is organized, I'm going to have to update those references manually in every single file!

I'm wondering if there's a workaround for this? Possibilities would include references which are relative to the project root, or automatic discovery of tsd typings in parent directories.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm wondering if there's a workaround for this

Yes. Use a tsconfig.json file : https://github.com/TypeStrong/atom-typescript/blob/master/docs/tsconfig.md With that you *don't need reference comments*.

Comment: This seems like a great solution, however it's not currently supported by Visual Studio. Damn it!